# Google Sheets: why did the designers of Google Sheet choose this operators precedence: -2^2 == (-2)^2 == 4? Any reason?

Tags: google-sheets

[image]

Why did the designers of Google Sheet choose this operators precedence: `-2^2 == (-2)^2 == 4` ?

Any reason?

I prefer the following precedence: `-2^2 == -(2^2) == -4`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is historical.

Google sheets was released decades after other spreadsheet software was available. Google sheets had to get the same answers as other spreadsheet software would, otherwise there would be zero consistency between providers.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I have not used Microsoft Excel yet. Does Microsoft Excel really return "4" for the input "=-2^2" ?

Comment: Yes. I checked before writing the answer.

Comment: Thank you very much, mhoran_psprep!

Comment: Note that this quirk only applies to the [unary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unary_function) operator `-`. The very similar [binary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_function) operator `-` uses the expected precedence — i.e., `10 - 2^2` === `6`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your information, doubleunary.